# Page A have iframe if I click on page B and go back to page A , the iframe disappear

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, next.js

I'm using Next.js
you can check the website here https://joe-mechlinski.vercel.app/
The iframe in the index page, try to go to another page and go back to the index page
you will see the Twitter iframe disappear.

```
// TwitterFrame Component
import Script from "next/script";

const TwitterFrame = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <section className="twitter-sec flex flex-col mt-20 items-center justify-center   bg-[#110b57]">
        <div className="pt-16 md:w-1/2 loadIframe">
          <a
            className="twitter-timeline"
            data-height="500"
            data-theme="light"
            href="https://twitter.com/joemechlinski?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw"
          >
            Tweets by joemechlinski
          </a>
          <iframe
            id="twitter-widget-0"
            scrolling="no"
            frameBorder="0"
            allowFullScreen={true}
            className="twitter-timeline twitter-timeline-rendered"
            data-widget-id="profile:joemechlinski"
            title="Twitter Timeline"
          />
          <Script
            src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"
            charSet="utf-8"
            strategy="afterInteractive"
            onError={(e) => {
              console.error("Script failed to load", e);
            }}
            onLoad={(e) => console.log(e)}
          ></Script>
        </div>
        <a
          href="https://twitter.com/joemechlinski?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw"
          className="text-white font-normal text-base bg-[#5541D9] py-4 px-8 -mt-12 mb-12"
        >
          Follow Along
        </a>
      </section>
    </>
  );
};

export default TwitterFrame;
```

Comment: Check the browser's console, you're getting a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerText')` when navigating back. I'd start by investigating that locally.

Comment: ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerText')``` This error comes from the about page when the counters section run @juliomalves

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. The code you provided isn't enough to reproduce the issue.

Comment: you can check the code from my repo here https://github.com/noureddein/joe-mechlinski/tree/main/components/home